# Copy large list of files from one location to another

Tags: python

(Using Python 3.4.2) 
I'm trying to copy a list of over 8,000 files in different locations to a staging directory.
The source path would look something like this D:\dir\img0\000 and the destination path D:\stage2\NW000.tif.

From what I understand shutil can take care of this, I've found simple example on the web which I've been trying to adapt to work for my purpose. I've saved the 8,000+ records of the source and destination paths in two separate text files with line breaks after each directory path. I want the variables src and dst to store all the values of the lists and shutil.copy to copy the files to their new destination. I've been trying to test the code by creating 1 source folder and 3 dest. folders: Test, TestA, TestB, TestC. I've created two text files with a list of paths, here is how they look:

```
(source.txt)
C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Test\t1.txt
C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Test\t2.txt
C:\Users\user1\Desktop\Test\t3.txt

(dest.txt)
C:\Users\user1\Desktop\TestA\1t.txt
C:\Users\user1\Desktop\TestB\2t.txt
C:\Users\user1\Desktop\TestC\3t.txt
```

I saved the two list text files, three dummy text files and the script in the Test directory and executed the script but I didn't find the files in the destination directories. I want to know why this script isn't working (where to place the source, dest, and script files in order for the script to execute properly).:

```
import shutil
import errno

file = open('source.txt', 'r')
source = file.readlines()
file = open('dest.txt', 'r')
destination = file.readlines()


def copy(src, dst):
    try:
        shutil.copytree(src, dst)
    except OSError as e:
        # If the error was caused because the source wasn't a directory
        if e.errno == errno.ENOTDIR:
            shutil.copy(src, dst)
        else:
            print('Directory not copied. Error: %s' % e)

copy(source, destination)
```

Comment: Your function definition is after your call. Change that first.

Comment: @BhargavRao I placed the function call after the definition, but it hasn't changed in anything as far as the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`shutil.copytree(src, dst)` copies *one* directory tree from `src` to `dst`. It does not automatically iterate over lists of files. You could try zipping source and destination lists and looping of the resultant list:

```
for src, dst in zip(source, destination):
    copy(src, dst)
```

You might also run into problems when you fallback to `shutil.copy(src, dst)` - this will fail if the destination directory does not already exist.

Comment: I zipped both the source and dest text files, and then ran the script, with the coded you suggested, a dos prompt opens and many paths scroll down, I get an error message at the end but it's too quick for me to read what it is. Are there any ways to catch this error?

Comment: Run your script directly from a command window - run `cmd.exe` to open one - this way the command window remains open at the end of the script and you can scroll up to see the error messages. Also, you could wrap your call to `copy()` in a bare try/except block to catch all exceptions, then call raw_input() to wait for user input before ending the script. To aid debugging, how about reducing the size of your lists so there is only a few files?

Comment: thanks for the tip, I ran the script from the command line and it only copied the last dummy text file to the appropiate destination. and I got this error for the preceding two : Directory not copied. Error: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\lfhernandez\\Desktop\\Test\\t2.txt\n'

Comment: There's something going on in the way the directory path is fed into the source variable. There's a double \ character and a line break escape sequence but im not sure why. I made sure that the source text file has no spaces after each line, but only the last line is being copied correctly.

Comment: For one thing you need to strip off the trailing new line character in each file name string - `file.readlines()` leaves the new lines in place. Use `file.read().splitlines()` instead. Probably there is no new line character in the last line of the file, hence the last file is successfully copied.

Comment: You are correct, I added the splitlines() call and it worked without a hiccup.

Comment: Great. Please consider accepting this answer if it was helpful to you (and correct).